# Integral of differential 1-form - Definition

Tags: integration, differential-forms

I am currently reading Arnold's book on ordinary differential equations and I came across the definition of the integral of a differential 1-form on a closed segment of a curve. Arnold  says that if 
$\gamma : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
is a smooth mapping, $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval, $\Gamma = \gamma(I)$ and $\omega = adx + bdy$ is a differential 1-form (where $a, b$) are smooth functions of the plane, then the integral of $\omega$ is defined as $$\int_{\Gamma} \omega = \int_{I} \omega(\gamma ')du$$
However, adopting the definition I saw in another analysis textbook, the integral would be $$\int_{\Gamma} \omega = \int_{I} \left(a(\gamma(u))\gamma_1'(u) + b(\gamma(u))\gamma_2'(u)\right)du$$
where $\gamma_i, i = 1, 2$ are the components of $\gamma$.

These two definitions seem different to me... or am I misreading Arnold's definition?

Comment: If $\omega = a\,dx + b\,dy$, these are precisely the same thing.

Comment: I don't get it. Where are the arguments of $a$ and $b$ coming from (that is $\gamma(u)$)?

Comment: The notation is a bit sloppy. You have to evaluate $\omega$ at the point $\gamma(u)$ [$a$ and $b$ are functions on the plane] and then apply it to the tangent vector $\gamma'(u)$. You might find the lectures on differential forms and line/surface integrals among my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile)  helpful.

Comment: Ok now I get it, thanks.